# Vue.js to create a button using v-bind

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cdn

I'm having trouble running components using Vue. I don't know if I'm using the correct CDN links, but it seems like it's not working at all.

**Template**

```
<div id="app">
    <button v-on:click="showing = !showing">show or hide</button>

    <transition name="slide-fade" tag="div">
        <div v-if="showing">Hello!</div>
    </transition>
    <weather-meter></weather-meter>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="weather-meter-template">
    <div>
        Today's high: {{high}}
        <div class="pointer" v-bind:style:="{width: showHigh}"></div>
        How we  feel about this: {{ourFeelings}}
    </div>
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
    new Vue({
    el:'app',
    data: function(){
        return{
            showing: true
        }
    }
});
    Vue.component("weather-meter", {
        template:"#weather-meter-template",
        data:function (){
            return{
                high:40,
                shownHigh: 40,
                ourFeelings: "meh"
            }
```

These are the CDN scripts I'm using as well.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The CDN link is ok. Your JS seems to have syntax errors, but it may comes from the copy/paste on SO. Does the JS console say something?

Comment: move your component in front of new Vue.